# Game maker studio place_meeting

Tags: variables, game-maker, gml

```
//obj 1 has that:
if (place_meeting(x,y, obj_nomatter)){
 global.points -= 1;
 moveawayfromobj_nomatter();
 // obj 1 rotates.
}
```

The problem is that the points drops sometimes one or seven.
Any ideas for algorithms? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is vague and lacks context. Please revise it so it is clear to us what you want to do, what outcome you expect...and what you are getting instead

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using that in the step event
so it calls the action one or seven times if you still collide for seven steps

one method is to use a timer or a variable

so:
this is the method using the variable

```
var ones = false;
if(!ones) {
  if(place_meeting(x,y,obj_nomatter)) {
    global.points -= 1; 
    ones = true;
  }
}
```

this is the method using the timer

```
step event:
if(place_meeting(x,y,obj_nomatter)) {alarm[0] = room_speed;} 
//to use the room_speed, 30 for default (a second)

alarm[0]:
global.points -= 1;

//with this method if you collide more than room_speed global.points keeps going down
```